# iPad 2 restarting intermittently and very slow to operate and charge

Tags: ios, ipad, software, charging

I have an iPad 2 (Model MC769B/A) running on iOS 6.1.3 (10B329) and over the past few days I have experienced *very* slow charging times when plugged into the usual source - the main wall socket.

Also, I have had a number of intermittent restarts even when I am in the middle of something. The screen just goes black and then the apple logo appears 2-3 seconds later and the device appears to reboot.

I have tried closing all application running in the task manager (double clicking the home button) and doing a hard reset (holding the home button and power button) but neither seem to have any effect.

I'm also noticing that the power the device holds is erratic at best, as I had zero charge this morning - completely flat, no power - at then plugged it into the wall and after 5 mins it was at 36% then after 2 mins was at 18% (!).

Does this sound like a hardware or software problem? What else can I try to remedy?

Comment: If possible, I would schedule an appointment at the Genius Bar at an Apple Store. They will be able to run hardware diagnostic tests which would more definitely determine whether it is hardware or software. You could always try wiping/restoring the device yourself, just to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just to cover the basics, I'd try a restore before taking it to the Apple Store for service. Sounds like hardware though, IMO.

Comment: Unfortunately a restore from a backup did not do the trick. It does indeed point to a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

This mimics the experience I had when using an iPhone 3G battery on my 3GS, suggesting an issue with the battery connector, the on-battery circuit or the serial line that interfaces with it.

Symtomps would be erratical battery indications, extremely slow charging regardless of the power available, ultimately resulting in the battery discharging non-linearly and running out with as much as 30% capacity displayed, hanging for significant fractions of an hour at the "Charging but delaying boot as battery is less than 5% full" followed by an equally long reboot loop as this slow charging fought against the increased drain of the more-than-minimum-brightness backlight.

If your device is jailbroken, checking with BatteryInfoLite will show a wildly incorrect temperature readout and a battery serial number of 0.

Restores will fail with error 27 or 29 unless the problem is fixed or the error is bypassed with a Fix Recovery utility (which is not applicable to your device).

Comment: I took it to the Apple store this afternoon and they quite quickly changed it for me at no cost, it's like-for-like but I notice a slight difference in the model number - previously it was `MC769B/A` and this one is a `MC769B`. I can't find anything online that states what the difference is.

Comment: Glad you got a new one!